# phpseclib-SSH2 -> Create an environment variable with the exec-command

Tags: php, phpseclib, ssh2-exec

I am working on a PHP-application, with which I can connect to a RaspberryPI (running Linux) via SSH2 of the phpseclib.
Connecting to a device and getting information over the "ls"- oder "pwd"-commands is working fine.

But now I am trying to create a new environment variable - let's say TEST_VAR - on a device, but this seems not to work.

Following my php-code to try that:

```
$ssh = new Net_SSH2($host, $port, 10);
if (!$ssh->login($user, $pass)) {
    exit("Login Failed");
}

// Test->Show the working directory
echo $ssh->exec("pwd");
// Create an environment variable "TEST_VAR" with the value "Test"
echo $ssh->exec("export TEST_VAR=Test");
// Give the content of the above created variable out
echo $ssh->exec("echo \$TEST_VAR");
```

The creation of the variable does not work
and I can not figure out why - because there are no errors.
Is this even possible with the phpseclib?

I would be very thankful for any help and hints.

Regards
Simon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$ssh->exec` doesn't preserve state. So, similarily, you can't do `$ssh->exec('cd /some/random/path'); echo $ssh->exec('pwd')` and expect it to output `/some/random/path`.

You have a few options.

1. Chain the commands. eg. `$ssh->exec("pwd; export TEST_VAR=Test; echo \$TEST_VAR");`
2. Use interactive mode. eg. `$ssh->read('[prompt]'); $ssh->write("pwd\n"); $ssh->read('[prompt]'); $ssh->write("export TEST_VAR=Test\n");`
3. Put all the commands you want to run into a shell script and then run the shell script.

More info:

http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/ssh/examples.html#chdir